# Is a htaccess file different on apache running on a windows server

Tags: windows, .htaccess

I am building a website on a windows server running apache and need to use a .htaccess file for pretty urls. If I add the .htaccess file it is just ignored, do I need to use somehting else? Is a .htaccess ignored on a windows server?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you sure it's called `.htaccess` with the dot in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be different, although I haven't used Apache on Windows for a long time.
Check the values of any occurrences of the following for the affected directory, or a location in which the affected directory resides:

**AccessFileName** - this *should* be set to .htaccess

**AllowOverride**  - this *should not* be set to *None*

Also, make sure that any modules that you are trying to use are enabled:
httpd -M

Answer (score 0):

No, it should be the same. Just make sure you have the appropriate modules enabled, in this case mod_rewrite and make sure that in your httpd.conf you allow the directives that you need to be used from the .htaccess files and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess file is parsed by Apache not the operating system so it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your replys, it turns out the server doesn't actually have Apache on and is running IIS sorry about wasting your time.

The owner installed http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/ module which allows htaccess files.